# Appending before-route to template in vuejs

Tags: vue.js

I would like to do something like this:

```
<router-link  :to="{name: 'home'}"
              before-enter="fooMethod">
      Click here
</router-link>
```

basically, I would like to call a method before the route is changed.

I have solved the problem with this approach:

```
<div @click="pushToRoute()">Click here</div>

// Methods
pushToRoute(){
  this.globalVariable = "changed";
  this.$route.push({name: 'home'})
}
```

But the problem with this approach is that it's not rendered in the HTML the `<a href="/">` attribute therefore not contributing for SEO. Is there any way to achieve the rendering of the attribute `<a ...>` while calling a method before leaving the route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something before leaving the route by using an [in-component navigation guard](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards). It has access to `this`, which means that you can use any data in the component, as well as the store to modify something (synchronously), or read something to make a decision if you want the navigation to go through. In your case you probably want to use `beforeRouteLeave`.

```
  beforeRouteLeave(to, from, next) {
    this.dummyCounter++;

    if (this.dummyCounter % 4 !== 0) {
      // Stay where we are
      next(from.fullPath);
      return;
    }

    // Always call next to continue, or it will forever stay in limbo
    next();
  }
```

Depending on what you want to accomplish, you may want to use global navigation guards instead (e.g. when working with transitions for example, or if something needs to happen for a couple of pages). You would call `beforeEach` on the router instance in that case and perform your magic there.

[image: Edit Appending before-route to template in vuejs]